# Night VFR in France

Tags: visual-flight-rules, night-flying, france

I would like to conduct a night VFR in France and I am looking for the special regulations (references) for the following questions

1. If an airport is approved for night VFR and nothing is mentioned on the VAC map, can I land/takeoff at anytime during the night? How does it work with landing fees?
2. Can I exit the airport easily if I land after ATS hours?
3. Is the windsock always illuminated ?
4. On the Flight Information frequency, is there  always someone available during 
   the night ?

Comment: I think each question should be asked separately (i'm tempted to flag the question as too broad, especially for the 2nd subquestion).

Comment: What is the airport you're looking at ?
Some airport tower have a 24h guard, non towered airport you need to ask someone on the ground for authorization.
FIS is in auto-information during night, there's only someone during daytime